# Dynamically add text boxes as user types into the last text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-manipulation

I have an ordered list, within the ordered list I'd like to have two text boxes per list element.  I would then like to append at the end of my ordered list another list element  containing two text boxes as the user types into the last text box of the last element.

I have JQuery code that looks like this:

```
$("ol li input:last-child").change(function(){
    $("ol").append('<li>Name: <input type="text"/><input type="text"/></li>');
});
```

My HTML looks something like this.

```
<ol>
    <li><input type="text"/><input type="text"/></li>
    <li><input type="text"/><input type="text"/></li>
</ol>
```

What I want is for a new list element (containing two text boxes) to be added at the end of the list when the user types into the last element such that the user could conceivably continue typing until the user is done.

What happens at the moment is that the user can type into the last input box of any current list element and my code will create another list element but then typing into the newly created list element (which should now be the last child) doesn't create an additional list element as I had hoped for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("ol").on('change', 'li:last input:last-child', function(){
    $(this).closest('ol').append('<li>Name: <input type="text"/><input type="text"/></li>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Dfsnr/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `.on()` for that.

```
$(document).on('change','ol li:last input:last-child',function()
{
    $("ol").append('<li>Name: <input type="text"/><input type="text"/></li>');
});
```

because your `DOM` is dynamically added so `change event`
 will not be applied to that dynamically loaded content so `.on` will help for that.

#### [**`Official Document`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> `Description`: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Comment: will fail if there is more than one `ol` in the page

Comment: You need to add a new `li` only if the last `input` field in the last `li` is edited

Comment: @ArunPJohny so what does your solution make difference in that...??? both are same....If OP want to be more specific then OP can use `ID` for `DOM`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny if you see second argument inside of `.on()` you will see it will apply only to `last-child`

Comment: @ArunPJohny okay i got what you are saying...you say last li right..??

Comment: Thank you both for your help in this manner. @ArunPJohny your solution worked best for me and what I wanted.  Just to clarify I wanted the last input element of the last list element.  Also that fiddle site is awesome!